# How to deploy a mvn application as an Azure web app

Tags: java, azure

I am working on a project to deploy a simple mvn application as an Azure web application. I continue to get the same error.

[image]

The folder structure for the application is:

[image]

I've tried placing the view directory in multiple locations since the controller is returning some form of the view.  The application.yml file is written like so

```
server:
  port: 80
 
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: view/
      suffix: .jsp
  profiles:
    active: dev
  main:
    banner-mode: off
```

After logging on to the app service registration via ssh I can see that there aren't any files saved on the server.

[image]

Expected: The webapp returns the view word_match.jsp when a GET request is made to /wordmatchgenerator.

Actual: whitelabel 404 error

Comment: before going to azure, is your application working locally as required? when using java, you won't see any files saved on the server (not like php stuff and all). It will be just a jar file and you will have to run jar file (like `java -jar app.jar`) in order to get things going.

Comment: My app runs locally

Comment: That's a good start. I think you are deploying on the wrong platform. If I am not mistaken, wwwroot is for ISS server and java does not run on that. Could you try to deploy your app as suggested in this article; https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/azure

Comment: Adding to atish.s, on App Service environment if you need to JAR deploy a web app, the file should be named “app.jar” for the deployment to succeed. And it needs to be placed in “/home/site/wwwroot” directory.                                                                    
 .If using a different file name then a startup command is needed to read the file. A sample would be “ java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/<filename>.jar”.            

Add start file as: 
the command to start your JAR app (for example, java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar --server.port=80)

Comment: You need to make sure your JSP files are copied under /wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/

.Add -[Pre-Compile JSP files](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#pre-compile-jsp-files) 

Deploy as per the sample [spring-boot-java-app-on-linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-on-linux) and customize.

Answer (score 0):

site/wwwroot is usually an ISS server and java do not need to be deployed on that.

Deploy your java application as proposed by Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-linux

I find this article straightforward (use do not create the vaadin app, use what you have).

https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/azure

Comment: I followed this, but the issue is that the files cannot be saved on the machine. When I list the file contents only app.jar and hostingstar.html shows up.

Comment: could please advice on which files are you referring to? if you're using maven, then the only "end-product" will be the jar file; which is the app.jar.

Comment: the application stores files on the server which are then rendered once the service is started.

Comment: Are you referring to the jsp files?

Comment: Yes I am referring to the jsp files.

Comment: the jsp files are all bundled in the jar file and you will need to run the jar file in order to get the application running. I propose you do some reading about what maven is and how it works.